# jUnit test doesn't output anything

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am new to jUnit and I am running a test for the output of when the program is run.

My jUnit test is:

```
class Tests {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new
            ByteArrayOutputStream();


    @BeforeEach
     public void setUpStreams() {
     System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
     }

    @AfterEach
     public void cleanUpStreams() {
     System.setOut(null);
     }

     @Test
     public void Test1() {
     Mobile ios = new Mobile();
     ByteArrayInputStream inContent = new 
     ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes());
     System.setIn(inContent);
     Mobile.main(new String[0]);
     System.setIn(System.in);
     assertNotEquals("Welcome!"+System.lineSeparator(),outContent.toString());
     }
}
```

Part of my program is:

```
public class MobileApp {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome!");

}
}
```

I am expecting the test to pass as the outputs are supposed to be the same. However, after running the test, it fails as it shows that nothing has actually been outputted. I am unsure of why this is so any help is appreciated. 
[Result Comparison after run of test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G9oE.png)

Comment: You cannot call a static method like this--`ios.main(new String[0]);`

Comment: @raviiii1 Thanks for your help. What would you suggest is the best way to write the test?

Comment: I suggest you go through some JUnit tutorials. One link is here https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Comment: @raviiii1 As per your suggestion, I conducted more research. However, I am now getting a different issue (explained in the post). I would very much appreciate it if you could take a look. Regards/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this might happen because of buffering in the `PrintStream`. You can pass `true` for an [autoFlush parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream(java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean)) when constructing the `PrintStream` to fix the problem, e.g.

```
 @BeforeEach
 public void setUpStreams() {
      System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent, true));
 }
```